# Blender only rendering one frame from animation - Using Cell Fracturing

Tags: rendering

The animation is 40 frames long, however Blender will only repeat the first frame 40 times.

I have tried changing the output format (I.e. PNG) but does not change anything. I just get 40 *.png files.
[image]

http://www.mediafire.com/file/1dcy81gt9967r5j/Explosion.blend/file

Comment: Have you baked the simulation ?

Comment: No. I've just been looking into that. Do you know how to bake Cell Fracture animations? I will keep looking. Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press here and bake it for render.

[image]